# ionic problems with accents when export to Excel

Tags: angularjs, excel, ionic-framework

I have the following code to export a HTML table into Excel but when this contains accents, this apears malformed.

In the HTML I have the string "ANDRÉS" and in the Excel appears this "ANDRÃS"

```
var strContent = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];

const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.table_to_sheet(strContent, {});

const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'Sheet1');

const wbout: string = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'binary' });

saveAs(new Blob([this.s2ab(wbout)]), 'inscripciones_' + this.eventcode +'.xlsx');
```

How I can do to export the Excel with the correct characters?

Thanks in advance,
Andrés

Comment: Did you try encoding for your objects?

something like encoding.ISO_XXX

Comment: How I can do it?

Comment: First I would try type: 'string' instead of type: 'binary' as per docs: https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx#output-type

Comment: If I change the type to 'string' return the next error: Error: 'string' output type invalid for 'xlsx' files